# How to include location blocks in nginx?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm using `nginx` as a reverse proxy for 2 web apps.

Those 2 web apps (UI) are sharing location proxies, as the backend services are shared.

How can I combine location blocks and include them in the servers?

**host.conf**

```
server {
  server_name app1.com
  listen 8080;
  ...

  include /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/vhosts/proxy.conf;
}

server {
  server_name app2.com;
  listen 8080;
  ...

  include /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/vhosts/proxy.conf;
}
```

**proxy.conf**

```
location /api/videos {
  proxy_pass ...
}
...
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
"location" directive is not allowed here in /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/vhosts/proxy.conf:2
```

Comment: Is the `vhost` folder being included via the `nginx.conf`?

Answer (score 18):

You need to change the file extension, change `proxy.conf` to `proxy.locations`.

Comment: Where is this required file extension documented? Why is this the only answer on the internet that mentions this?

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but I support @EricGuan question - where is this documented? How could we know this extension is required?

Comment: I could not find anything in the documentation, but observed that the root `nginx.conf` configuration file has `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` in the `http` section. This implies, any extension other than `.conf` will work, because `*.conf` themselves will be automatically included in `http` section.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents here:
if you have `include /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/vhosts/*.conf;` in `nginx.conf` it will also try to include `proxy.conf` in the config root where `location` directive is not allowed, having a different extension avoid that.

to be tested but I think `.conf` should work if you have a more precise include in the `nginx.conf`