# Splitting configuration nginx configuration when have many location in the same domain

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

i have a virtual server that have many location directives in nginx. now is it possible to split into different files?

my default.conf

```
server {
listen 443;
server_name my.domain.com;

location /a { ... }
location /b { ... }
location /c { ... }
}
```

want to change to:

```
server {
listen 443;
server_name my.domain.com;
include /etc/nginx/location/*.conf
}
```

inside /etc/nginx/location/ i will have a.conf, b.conf, and c.conf

a.conf config file

```
location a/ {...}
```

b.conf config file

```
location /b {...}
```

c.conf config file

```
location /c {...}
```

thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do that? When you tried, did it work?

Comment: i create dns over https service, and want to make many location and pass it into different upstream each of location. if its possible so if i want to create new location i just want to automate the creation of location conf file using shell script.

Comment: There’s probably a better duplicate but: Does this answer your question? [How to include location blocks in nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55691000/how-to-include-location-blocks-in-nginx)