# How paste another location before first match in file by command sed/awk/another?

Tags: awk, sed

I need dynamic change nginx config for ci, try work it out by sh script.

But i'm zero in sh scripts, i know only what i see in google.

Input:

```
server {

    #location /api/graphql {
    #       modsecurity off;
    #       proxy_pass http://10.1.0.4;
    #}

    location 73347347 {
        proxy_pass 123;
    }

    location 123 {
        proxy_pass 123;
    }

    location / {
            modsecurity off;
            proxy_pass http://10.1.0.4;
    }

}
```

test.sh

```
location="
    location /projects/$1/$2 {
        proxy_pass http://10.1.0.6:$3; #where $arg, on output i just show $1 for example
    }"

#sed "/.*#location/! s/.*location/$location\n\n&/" file
#sed "/.*#location/!s/.*location/$location\n\n&/" file
#sed "/#location/n;/location/i 0000" file

awk "!done && match($0,/^([[:space:]]*)location/,a){print a[1] $location ORS; done=1} 1" file
```

***./test.sh test 2.0.0 5000***

Output:

```
server {

    #location /api/graphql {
    #       modsecurity off;
    #       proxy_pass http://10.1.0.4;
    #}

    location /projects/test/2.0.0 {
        proxy_pass http://10.1.0.6:5000;
    }

    location 73347347 {
        proxy_pass 123;
    }

    location 123 {
        proxy_pass 123;
    }

    location / {
            modsecurity off;
            proxy_pass http://10.1.0.4;
    }

}
```

I have worrking command, but she paste before all matches:

`sed "/.*#location/! s/.*location/$location\n\n&/" file`

Comment: Not an answer to your question, for reverse proxy you might consider traefik, fabio , haproxy , consul . | How about putting your configuration in /etc/nginx/nginx.d directory and just updating one whole file with new content, instead of modyfing?

Comment: No, because i need add location for subdomain, not another server

Comment: I do not follow, so include a file with location for the subdomain, not another server. Example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55691000/how-to-include-location-blocks-in-nginx

Comment: I need to do it automatically anyway, so this line has to be inserted by a script, so what's the difference?

```
include /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/vhosts/proxy.conf;
```

Comment: i can use *.conf and maybe this is good, but i want do this for start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

location='\
    location /projects/'"$1/$2"' {
        proxy_pass http://10.1.0.6:$3; #where $arg, on output i just show $1 for example
    }
'

awk -v loc="$location" '
    !done && ($1 == "location") {
        print loc
        done = 1
    }
    { print }
' file
```

```
$ ./tst.sh test 2.0.0
server {

    #location /api/graphql {
    #       modsecurity off;
    #       proxy_pass http://10.1.0.4;
    #}

    location /projects/test/2.0.0 {
        proxy_pass http://10.1.0.6:$3; #where $arg, on output i just show $1 for example
    }

    location 73347347 {
        proxy_pass 123;
    }

    location 123 {
        proxy_pass 123;
    }

    location / {
            modsecurity off;
            proxy_pass http://10.1.0.4;
    }

}
```

See [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) for more information on how to pass the content of a shell variable to an awk script.

The above awk script is simpler than the one in [the answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77862923/1745001) because here you're providing the indenting for the new text in the variable definition whereas with the previous one we had to figure out the indent from the existing input.

Comment: Thx u, its works! For write to file i need rewrite file like *./tst.sh arg arg arg > file*?

Comment: no, don't need, similar sed args https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/496179/how-to-change-a-file-in-place-using-awk-as-with-sed-i

Thx u very much!

Comment: You're welcome (for the answer and for [`gawk -i inplace`](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2012-12/msg00046.html) :-) ).